# typescript - define interface in different file, tslint give me a warning

Tags: typescript

I begin to learn `typescript`, and when I define two `interface` with the same name in two files, `tslint` give me a warning:

[image]

Here are my two files:

`./src/interface/define-an-interface.ts`:

```
interface Accountable{
  getIncome(): number;
}

class Firm implements Accountable{  //<- tslint give me a hint for `Firm`
  getIncome(): number {
    return 2222;
  }

  //I do not need implement the property accountNumber here, because 
  //within this file, the `Accountable` interface does not define 
  // `accountNumber` property.
}
```

`./src/interface/interface-inherit.ts`:

```
interface Accountable{
  accountNumber: string;
  getIncome(): number;
}
```

It's weird. I did not define two `interface` with the same name in one file.
Why `tslint` throw a warning?

-- update --

I think the two files are fully independent and the code of `./src/interface/define-an-interface.ts` file should be totally correct.

I defined the interface `Accountable` with property `accountNumber: string;` in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Updated

Because you can use it as an optional parameter

```
interface Accountable {
  accountNumber?: string;
  getIncome(): number;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to `export`. I define `Accountable ` interface in first file and `implement` it with `Firm` class. Is it a wrong that `ts` does not allow define `interface` with same name in two files?

Comment: I know that. I am familiar with `es2015` module system. Here, I just do some practice about `ts`. so, focus my question.

Comment: clearly look into it. will any one define interfaces twice with the same name?

Comment: My question is why `tslint` give me an warning in `./src/interface/define-an-interface.ts` file,  I think I do nothing wrong in this file. I define `Accountable ` with property `accountNumber: string;`  in another file. I think the two files are not affect each other.

Comment: you are not referring to particular Accountstable by importing from the concerned file